# Get RedirectToPage Generated URL ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

You are able to redirect to other actions using built-in methods like:

```
RedirectToPage("./Index", new { StatusMessage = "Everything was processed successfully"" });
```

This will redirect to another `PageModel` that's in same directory and it's Index action. Is it possible to "extract" this functionality so that you get redirect location by just passing `./Index` to some util function/method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    public void OnGet()
    {
        string privacyPageUrl = Url.Page("./Privacy");
    }
}
```